# Unable to show Admob ads in android activity

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to implement Admob ads in android activity but after everything done as per instruction given on firebase-Admob ads integration guide there is problem in showing ads in activity.What I have done so far is:

**AndroidManifest.XML**

```
 <meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
  android:value="MY_APP_ID" />
```

**XML**

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ad_View"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="MY_ADUNIT_ID">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**Java**

```
public class Ad extends AppCompatActivity {

AdView ad_View;
AdRequest adRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ad);

    MobileAds.initialize(this,@string/appid);

    ad_View = findViewById(R.id.adView);

    ad_View = new AdView(this);
    ad_View.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    ad_View.setAdUnitId(@string/adunit);

   MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

        }
    });

    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    ad_View.loadAd(adRequest);
   }
}
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Why you are setting `ad_View.setAdSize()` from both XML and inside activity ?

Comment: Have you referred to this [doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

Comment: Can you please explain more about your problem?? have to added Internet permissions in AndroidManifest.XML ??

Comment: Read thie [**Make sure you set the ad size and ad unit ID in the same manner (i.e. set both in XML or both programmatically).**](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner)

Comment: `there is problem in showing ads in activity` which problem

Comment: Now problem has been resolved but there is Test ad label is showing on ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to remove this lines from your code,

```
ad_View = new AdView(this);
ad_View.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
ad_View.setAdUnitId(@string/adunit);
```

because you have already set in `XML`

So try this,

```
public class Ad extends AppCompatActivity {

AdView ad_View;
AdRequest adRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ad);

    MobileAds.initialize(this,@string/appid);

    ad_View = findViewById(R.id.adView);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

        }
    });

    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    ad_View.loadAd(adRequest);
   }
}
```

Note : Please make sure to add Internet Permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Now its working fine but why there is ad test label is showing on ads.Even if I am using my Ad unit it and app id provided by Admob.

Comment: It is better to use `MobileAds.initialize()` in a class which extends `Application` class.

Comment: @Digvijay Glad to know that it helps, Happy Coding :)